# Schaefer's dichotomy theorem - I do not understand the conditions

Tags: logic

We have [Schaefer's dichotomy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaefer%27s_dichotomy_theorem). I do not understand the last three conditions:

- all relations are equivalent to a conjunction of Horn clauses;
- all relations are equivalent to a conjunction of dual-Horn clauses;
- all relations are equivalent to a conjunction of affine formulae.

Can someone explain it to me on a very simple examples?
I do not understand in this case the "conjunction of Horn clauses", "conjunction of dual-Horn clauses" etc.

For example, I know what it is [Horn clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause). I do not understand, however, how to connect to the conjunction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint*

[Horn clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause) :

> is a disjunction of literals (a clause) with at most one positive, i.e. unnegated, literal

i.e. something like : $p \lor \lnot q \lor \lnot r$.

A conjunction of Horn clauses is thus a conjunction of two or more disjunctions of literals (each one with at most one unnegated literal), i.e. something like :

> $(p \lor \lnot q \lor \lnot r) \land (\lnot p \lor \lnot q \lor r)$.

---

A [dual-Horn clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause) is:

> a disjunction of literals with at most one negated literal.

Comment: Thank you very much. And about the "conjunction of affine formulas" could You write something?

Comment: @Marek Wolny  - See [affine formula](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/jair/pub/volume19/zanuttini03a-html/node7.html).

Answer (score 0):

Conjunctions of Horn and dual-Horn clauses can be solved by unit propagation without backtracking.  Affine formulae can be solved by Gaussian elimination.

An example of Gaussian elimination, where $\oplus$ denotes exclusive or.  Three affine formulae to be simultaneously satisfied are shown in matrix form; $a$, $b$, and $c$ are parameters.

$$\begin{matrix}
x_1 & \oplus & x_2 &        &     & = & a \\
    &        & x_2 & \oplus & x_3 & = & b \\
x_1 & \oplus &     &        & x_3 & = & c   
\end{matrix}
$$
Eliminate $x_1$ from the third equation by taking the exclusive or.  (Recall that $x_1 \oplus x_1 = \bot$.)
$$\begin{matrix}
x_1 & \oplus & x_2 &        &     & = & a \\
    &        & x_2 & \oplus & x_3 & = & b \\
    &        & x_2 & \oplus & x_3 & = & a \oplus c   
\end{matrix}
$$
Then eliminate $x_2$ from the third equation:
$$\begin{matrix}
x_1 & \oplus & x_2 &        &     & = & a \\
    &        & x_2 & \oplus & x_3 & = & b \\
    &        &     &        & \bot & = & a \oplus b \oplus c   
\end{matrix}
$$
The conjunction is satisfiable if $a \oplus b \oplus c = \bot$.  If that's the case, one can freely choose $x_3$, and proceed to back-substitution.  For example, if $c = a \oplus b$, one can choose $x_3 = b$.  Then, $x_2 = \bot$ and $x_1 = a$.